# Add to Timeline's button mode broken?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Though I've embedded the Add to Timeline social plugin in button mode:

```
<div class="fb-add-to-timeline" data-show-faces="false" data-mode="button"></div>
```

it keeps showing up as the full plugin including a preview of how Timeline items will look like. Is this a known issue?

I grabbed the embed code from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/#.

Comment: I don't have the same problem than you. I'm getting this instead 'myapp is under construction. Please try again later.'

Comment: So you don't see the full box and not the button either, right?

Comment: I see both. It's in the pop-up that I see this message. I don't know if it's related or not. There a bug report about the social plugin not showing up. (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/290625520953595)

Comment: I understand. I wanted to achieve the button-only mode, without the larger box. Does that work for you?

Comment: Nope, it's still the box mode even when I specified that I want the button mode… There are a lot of bugs reported about OpenGraph since yesterday… :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and just remove the "timeline" permission from my app settings, and then it showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Since the button is really just a permission trigger you can build around it with your actual access request. This is logical if you are doing an SDK call of all sort using javascript, php or other versions.

Of course as timeline is not enabled outside of dev, one would suspect this will be addressed soon as so far I'm seeing the box in just about any type of testing I do. Odds are Facebook wants to show the box when someone calls timeline specifically to build adoption understanding.

Comment: Could you possibly paste a JavaScript snippet which would request the Add to Timeline and Publishing permission that usually gets requested by the Add to Timeline Social Plugin? That would be wonderful!